# common Network on 2 dedicated ESXi servers

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, vlan, gateway, clearos

I have two ESXi dedicated servers from a cloud vendor.
Each server has two nic card, one is private and one attached with public gateway.

ESXi 1
- i created a vSwitch0 from public NIC and VMkernal and VMNetwork from that vSwitch
- i created a vSwitch1 from private NIC and PrivateVMNetwork from that vSwitch

In one VM i created a ClearOS gateway server using Public VMNetwork.
So all the VMs in group1 connected with VMNetwork got internet access.

ESXi 2
- i created a vSwitch1 from private NIC and PrivateVMNetwork from that vSwitch

all the VMs in group2 connected with Private VMNetwork not having internet access.

Note : ESXi 1 and 2 connected each other through NIC2

[image]

My problem is to make both the Group1 and Group2 VMs in same network,

i tried attaching the PrivateVMNetwork of ESXi 1 to gateway server, VMs in group 1 cannot connect to gateway
Tried bridging the VMNetwork and PrivateVMNetwork, it creates a loopback and whole network was disturbed.

What is solution for this kind of setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

ESXi vSwitches never switch packets back to the physical world once they've been received by a physical NIC. (You can do this in a VM but it's not really what you want.) What you're trying to build is a "super switch" encompassing both private and public NICs and all vSwitches. That switch would need to physically connect both host NICs in order to work - totally eliminating the physical public/private distinction.

Instead, the much better approach is to put two vNICs in each VM and have each of them connect to one of the vSwitches/port groups - one for public I/O, one for private. If you require multiple private port groups you'll need to map them to VLANs and have those supported on the physical, private switch.